# Is there a way to make Mathematica work with Parquet?

Tags: import

Has anyone tried to make Mathematica work with [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/)?
If so, what are the solution possibilities? And how can
this be made possible?

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1595622

Comment: What would you like us to do about this? This a community web site run by users, not administered or staffed by Wolfram. The most we can do is look at the documentation, same as you, and we have no insight about whether or not there are plans to support this. Perhaps someone has implemented their own support for Parquet - consider rewording your question to ask about that. You should also put in a feature request to Wolfram.

Comment: I did  but I also see the negativity surrounding the downvoting. this isn't the way to go about things.

Comment: You're right. The downvote was from me - the way your question was originally worded sounded, IMO, very negative towards the community and didn't ask an answerable question. Now that it's been reworded I've removed my downvote, and I've voted to reopen.

Comment: i didn't expect this much silence ... anyone ?